# Configure CKEditor plugin

Tags: wysiwyg

I have the autosave plugin for CKEditor enabled and working, but I want to change from some of the default settings (specifically save detection selectors and autosave_delay) and can't get the settings to "stick".  I have been editing ckeditor.config.js (in modules/patched/ckeditor/) and, while that's executing, the settings changes aren't making it to the editor instance running on the page.  I've also hacked at ckeditor.utils.js because I was able to get closer to the actual instance but I know that isn't best practice and I'll regret it down the road.

Drupal7 fyi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define (extra) config options in a CKEditor profile. Go to example.com/admin/config/content/ckeditor then select the editor profile(s) in which you have enabled autosave and go to the "Advanced Options".

In the "Custom JavaScript configuration" field you can override config options like

```
config.autosave_saveDetectionSelectors = "a[href^='javascript:__doPostBack'][id*='Save'],a[id*='Cancel']";
config.autosave_delay = 5;
```

No need to alter any of the javascript files.